# Disable Spaces shelf in Mission Control all windows Exposé

Tags: macos, spaces, window-manager, mission-control, expose

In recent versions of macOS, Mission Control's all windows view shows a shelf for your Spaces. When first activated, this shelf is collapsed at a small height at the top of the screen that displays each Space's title. If you move your mouse up and hover over that shelf, the shelf expands in height and a full thumbnail of each Space is shown.

> Mission Control activated via a Bottom Left or Bottom Right hot corner; note the collapsed-by-default Spaces shelf:
>
> [image]

The problem is that I use a "Top Right" hot corner to activate Mission Control, and have since that feature was released as Exposé in OS X 10.3 in 2003. Because that hot corner is located *above* that collapsed shelf, the Spaces shelf is fully expanded every time I use the hot corner. The collapsed view is never shown.

> Mission Control activated via a Top Left or Top Right hot corner; Spaces shelf always expanded:
>
> [image]

I would like to keep using the same hot corner due to muscle memory. But I don't use Spaces, so I would like to remove that space-wasting and [Exposé-spatial-layout](https://superuser.com/questions/118424/old-leopard-expose-on-snow-leopard-for-mac)-wrecking expanded Spaces shelf.

1. Can the Spaces shelf be disabled and hidden entirely from the Mission Control all windows view, for all activation methods? This would be like using old Exposé, before it was expanded to Mission Control.
2. Using a Top Left or Top Right activation hot corner for Mission Control, is there any way for the Spaces shelf to not be *immediately* displayed upon every activation? I wouldn't mind still seeing the collapsed view, but I want to expand the shelf intentionally by click or moving out and re-hovering.

Comment: I feel your pain. I've been searching for a way to disable the top spaces bar completely. I also use the upper right as the mission control hot corner, but I'm biting the bullet and switching to bottom right to avoid expanding the unnecessary spaces bar at the top. Old exposé was the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any **numbered** Space by hovering over it with your cursor, then clicking the X,

[image]

This only applies to user-created, numbered Spaces. Any created by using fullscreen are named not numbered & behave differently.

I'm not absolutely certain this will prevent the large shelf from showing, as it may retain the 'add new Space' icon at the right. [I have 7 carefully arranged pairs of Spaces I'm not willing to clear just to test ;)

Comment: Even if you only have one Desktop, the Spaces shelf unfortunately continues to show up expanded when triggered by a Top hot corner.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't test it. I don't know of any other way, short of just using a key command or mouse/trackpad gesture instead.